# How can we set fixed width for Query data tables if table has no header

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

In my project we have a Jquery datatable in which we dont need to show any headers. So i just hide the header like below

```
 <table id="dataTable1" class="ui celled table" style="width:100%">
                                                   <thead style="display:none">
                                                   </thead>
                                               </table>
```

But we have some fixed width defined in this table and because of no header the width is not taking based on our settings.

We have setting like below to do the fixed width.

```
 var dataTable1 = $('#dataTable1').DataTable({
            paging: false,
            dom: 't',
            lengthChange: false,
            ordering: false,
            info: true,
            bInfo: false,
            autoWidth: false,
            searching: true,
            serverSide: false,
            fixedHeader: false,
            fixedColumns: false,
            aaSorting: [],
            columnDefs: [
                { targets: 0, width: "40%" },
                { targets: 1, width: "40%" },
                { targets: 2, width: "20%" },
                {
                    "defaultContent": "-",
                    "targets": "_all"
                }
            ],
            columns: [
                { data: "Filed1"},
                { data: "Field2" },
                { data: "Field3"}
            ],
            ajax: {
                url: dataTable1Url,
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json"
            }
        });
```

Is there any way to set column width if we dont have any header in datatable. ?

I have tried to remove header using below code but still its removing header and the width which is added into the header is removed and the whole datatable width is kind of broken.

```
"drawCallback": function() {
  $(this.api().table().header()).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Added two css class like below

```
.width-40-percentage
{
    width:40%;
}
.width-20-percentage {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Then applied it in the datatable column definition

```
 columnDefs: [
                { targets: 0, width: "40%", className: 'width-40-percentage'},
                { targets: 1, width: "40%", className: 'width-40-percentage'},
                { targets: 2, width: "20%", className: 'width-20-percentage' },
                {
                    "defaultContent": "-",
                    "targets": "_all"
                }
            ],
```

Its working fine now.